# Incoming buffer size cannot be set to Tyrus client

Tags: java, websocket, glassfish, java-websocket, tyrus

I trying to transfer a file bigger than 4M via WebSocket. I'm using `org.glassfish.tyrus:tyrus-server:1.13.1` and `org.glassfish.tyrus:tyrus-container-grizzly-server:1.13.1` as dependencies.

By default the incoming buffer size is about 4M (see: [8.4. Incoming buffer size](https://tyrus-project.github.io/documentation/1.12/user-guide.html#d0e1197)). The documentation clearly says what needs to be done if I want to increase the size of the file but still can not change the incoming buffer size. Here is the essence of what I'm trying to do:

```
CountDownLatch messageLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

final ClientEndpointConfig cec = ClientEndpointConfig.Builder.create().build();
ClientManager client = ClientManager.createClient();

client.getProperties().put(ClientProperties.INCOMING_BUFFER_SIZE, new Integer(17_000_000));
Integer tyrusIncomingBufferSize = Utils.getProperty(client.getProperties(), ClientProperties.INCOMING_BUFFER_SIZE, Integer.class);
System.out.println("tyrusIncomingBufferSize: " + tyrusIncomingBufferSize); // 17000000

client.connectToServer(new Endpoint() {
    @Override
    public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig config) {
        try {
            session.addMessageHandler(new MessageHandler.Whole<ByteBuffer>() {

                @Override
                public void onMessage(ByteBuffer message) {
                    System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
                    messageLatch.countDown();
                }
            });

            File pic = new File(TEST_PIC); // the size is more than 4M
            FileInputStream fileReader = new FileInputStream(pic);
            final long sizeOfScreenshotFile = pic.length();
            System.out.println(sizeOfScreenshotFile); // 4734639
            byte[] screenshotData = new byte[(int) sizeOfScreenshotFile];
            fileReader.read(screenshotData);
            fileReader.close();

            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(screenshotData);
            session.getBasicRemote().sendBinary(bb);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}, cec, new URI(URI));
messageLatch.await(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

But I still have the same error:

```
17000000
4734639
V 30, 2017 1:39:58 PM org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusEndpointWrapper onError
WARNING: Unexpected error, closing connection.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Buffer overflow.
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.Utils.appendBuffers(Utils.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusWebSocketEngine$TyrusReadHandler.handle(TyrusWebSocketEngine.java:523)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.server.GrizzlyServerFilter$ProcessTask.execute(GrizzlyServerFilter.java:379)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.TaskProcessor.processTask(TaskProcessor.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.TaskProcessor.processTask(TaskProcessor.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.server.GrizzlyServerFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyServerFilter.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOUtils.flushByteBuffer(TCPNIOUtils.java:149)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOUtils.writeSimpleBuffer(TCPNIOUtils.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.processAsync(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeyEvents(SelectorRunner.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeys(SelectorRunner.java:384)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:348)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:279)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
-9.8634088E7
V 30, 2017 1:41:38 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener shutdownNow
INFO: Stopped listener bound to [0.0.0.0:8025]
V 30, 2017 1:41:38 PM org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server stop
INFO: Websocket Server stopped.
```

I tried to debug the Tyrus project and saw that the `incomingBufferSize` variable actually remained with the default value.

Does anyone have any idea how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the property in the client, but the exception is clearly thrown on the server.

How are you starting the server? It almost seems like you are using Grizzly standalone - if you do, you can try starting the server with [TyrusWebSocketEngine#INCOMING_BUFFER_SIZE](https://tyrus-project.github.io/apidocs/1.13.1/org/glassfish/tyrus/core/TyrusWebSocketEngine.html#INCOMING_BUFFER_SIZE) property set to `17_000_000` or whatever value you want.

(That can be done by creating the server by using [Server(Map, Class ...)](https://tyrus-project.github.io/apidocs/1.13.1/org/glassfish/tyrus/server/Server.html#Server(java.util.Map,%20java.lang.Class...)) or other constructors. See [Server class javadoc](https://tyrus-project.github.io/apidocs/1.13.1/org/glassfish/tyrus/server/Server.html) for more details.

Comment: I have solved a problem thanks to your response. I injected a map with the new incoming buffer size into the Server constructor and that solve my problem. Thanks а lot!

Answer (score 0):

Solution (thanks to @Pavel Bucek):

On the Server side:

```
Map<String,Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.put("org.glassfish.tyrus.incomingBufferSize", 17000000);
Server server = new org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server("localhost", 8025, null, 
                                               properties, TestServer.class);
```